# Reshape array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array of size `5000x32x32x3`. The number 5000 is the number of images and each image is `32x32` in width and height and has `3` color channels.

Now I would like to create a numpy array  of shape `5000x3x32x32` in a way that the data is preserved.
What I mean by preserving data is :

1. There should be 5000 data points in the resulting array
2. The 2nd dimension (`3`) of the array correctly determines the color channel i.e all the elements whose 2nd dimension is `0` belong to red channel, whose 2nd dimension is `1` belong to green channel,whose 2nd dimension is `2` belong to blue channel.

Simply reshaping the by `np.reshape(data,(5000,3,32,32))` would not work as it would not preserve the channels but just reshape the data into the desired shape.

Comment: Have you looked into: `numpy.swapaxes` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html . It should be doable by two axes transpositions.

Comment: Actually `np.transpose(data, (0,3,1,2))` should do what you want.

Comment: @Learningisamess you should write as an answer..

Comment: Today I decided to gave up fighting with Numpy and its notion of shape and table. I prefer to avoid to contact directly  with it (:-) whenever  possible. Sometimes, a simple program became mess when I have to .data or pass in numpy format. Panda knows it better than me, then I talk with him and to_numpy!.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for a permutation of the axes, `numpy.transpose` can get this job done:

```
data = np.transpose( data, (0, 3, 1, 2))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped!!